# Create-React-App: CSS custom classNames not loading properly in build version

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app to build a personal website and I'm having some issues with how CSS is being read in the deployed version of the site.

Here is my project folder tree: 
[image: project folder tree]

I have an `App.css` file containing the following `.Text` element:

```
.Text {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 80%;
  z-index: 1
}
```

Then, inside each component, I have an `import '../App.css'`
and then use `<div className="Text" id="componentName">` to wrap any text on the page.

When I run `npm run start` locally, I can see the text clearly rendered on a graphic background, as such: [image]

However, after running `npm run build` and opening the build locally, I see only the background image and no text. 
I was able to make the text visible on the build version by deleting the `.Text` element in `App.css`, but I want to display the styling for those text elements.

Any advice on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your App.css inside App.js only, you can use the classes in the components.